# Database geolocation which one is better

Tags: geolocation, ip, client-side

I am looking into getting a geolocation database. I am trying to understand the difference between a paid and a free service besides how accurate the results are.

I want to display data on the page based on the user's location. Should I user server side or client side to check the location and display the data accordingly? I can imagine how to do it server side, but not client side.

If I want to get the user's ip, country, region, city, and show the cities within x km around that city, I would also need the Latitude and Longitude correct?

I was looking at

http://freegeoip.net/

and

http://www.ip2location.com/databases#comparison 
**option: DB5**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest maxmind database for Geo location, I have used maxmind database for my 
[website](http://www.guesthouser.com)
the link of maxmind data base is-http://maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

Comment: Because it is so fast and implementation is easy.

Answer (score 0):

freegeoip uses maxmind GeoLite2 database. You could as well download it yourself (~25mb) and lookup on your server which would be faster.